# Кнопка назад Toolbar

Tags: java, android

Прочел документацию, и сделал как написано
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CreateActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ResetActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reset"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SelectActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

У меня два activity должны вернуться к LoginActivity, но во время нажатия стрелки назад идет к MainActivity, как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял то у вас на toolbar есть стрелка и вам нужно задать переход на определенную активность. Сама стрелка как вы вероятнее всего знаете добавляется так:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

дальше вам нужно переопределить функцию `onSupportNavigateUp` так:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
```

в моем случае эта функция обращается к функции нажатия на кнопку назад внизу экрана, то есть как-бы дублирует ее, но вообще можно задать что угодно при нажатии на эту кнопку, например переход на нужную вам активность:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
```

и я честно говоря не очень уверен что вам нужно что-то прописывать в манифесте, лично я ничего не прописывал для возврата на другую активность. Если возникнут сложности или какие-то вопросы, то с радостью поможем. Удачи :)

Comment: спасибо!! у меня есть другие Activity которые работают правильно без каких либо ошибок, но только вот эти два Activity не идут на parentActivity а к MainActivity, прописал заново NavigateUp и сработал!

Comment: всегда рад помочь :)